# The indices of maximum value in a 3-D tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor of size `[2,2,3]`, e.g., `A=tf.constant([[[1,2,-1],[3,4,-3]], [[5,6,-5],[-6, 7,8]]])`. I want to calculate the maximum indices for each row (thus 2d vector), i.e., the solution would be `[[1,1], [1,2]]`. How to do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

User [`tf.math.argmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
A = tf.constant([[[1, 2, -1], [3, 4, -3]], [[5, 6, -5], [-6, 7, 8]]])
idx = tf.math.argmax(A, axis=2)
tf.print(idx)
# [[1 1]
#  [1 2]]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as it is essentially the largest index of rows or row. E.g., if `A=tf.constant([[[1,2,-1],[3,4,-3],[5,6,7]], [[5,6,-5],[-6, 7,8],[8,9,10]]])`, then the answer given by argmax would be `<tf.Tensor: id=928, shape=(2, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 2]])>`, which seems incorrect (the correct shape should always be [n, 2]).

Comment: @JohnM. I'm sorry, but I don't follow, it's not clear to me from your question why the result should always be `[n, 2]`. Maybe you can edit the question and try to explain in a bit more detail what you need, indicating what should be the result for that second example you are giving (since the example in the question does work with my answer).

Comment: So in the original example, each row `r_i` is a `[2,3]` vector. The result of this row would be a `[2]` vector representing `(x_i, y_i)` such that `r_i[x_i, y_i]` is the maximum value in `r_i`. Would this be clearer?